# Is there a list of current publishers of the Talmud?

Tags: talmud-gemara

For example, Oz Vehadar, Koren, Artscroll, etc. Also would be very helpful to have the website for each publisher. Thank you so much

Comment: Meir, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887)! You could make this question more compelling by [edit]ing in why you want to have such a list. To get the ball rolling, I suggest that you post an answer yourself and add in as many publishers as you already know about, and check the "community wiki" box at the bottom-right of the answer box to indicate that you welcome additions from other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Un-Translated Versions

- **Oz VeHadar Talmud Bavli**

[Oz VeHadar Talmud Bavli](http://www.oz-vehadar.com/en/department/1/talmud-bavli)

Just your simple, Vilna Shas pages with no translation or commentary other than the classic commentaries like Rashi and Tosfos that appear on every Vilna Shas page. Many varieties available.

Vina Hachadash
Published by mesoras hashas and z. Berman

Talman
The first shas to bold the words of the gemara brought in Rashi

Vagshal

Tuvias
A shas with vowelization.

### English

- **The Schottenstein Edition Talmud Bavli**

[Full Size](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/TAL.html) | [Daf Yomi Size](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/DYT.html) | [Travel Size](http://artscroll.com/Categories/TRT.html)

Perhaps the most famous Talmud Bavli on the market. Pages set up according to the original Vilna Shas, with English elucidation of each phrase within the Gemara and commentary to aid in the reader's full understanding of each sugya. Full size and daf yomi sized sets contain 73 volumes, the travel sized set contains 146 paperback booklets.

[Example Page](http://www.artscroll.com/images/siteimages/ybr1_spread.gif) of the Schottenstein Edition Talmud Bavli in English

- **Koren Talmud Bavli Noé**

[Full Size](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/talmud/talmud-sets/talmud-bavli-noe-large-size-color-complete-set.html) | [Medium Size](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/talmud/talmud-sets/talmud-bavli-noe-medium-size-b-w-complete-set.html)

Currently trending in popularity, especially among Modern Orthodox Jews or anyone who enjoys a new, modern, look to classic sefarim. Contains commentary by [Rabbi Adin Steinsaltz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adin_Steinsaltz), a trustworthy and upright individual who is an expert in halacha. The full size edition comes with full color photos and diagrams!

[Example Page](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Koren_Talmud_Bavli.jpg) of the Koren Talmud.

- **Soncino Talmud Bavli**

[Soncino Talmud Bavli Set](http://www.soncino.com/product/the-soncino-talmud-set)

A classic English translation of the Talmud. To my knowledge, there is no commentary other than the classic commentaries like Rashi and Tosfos that is on every Vilna Shas page, and it is written in archaic English.

### Modern Hebrew

- **The Schottenstein Edition Talmud Bavli**

[Full Size](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/HBT.html) | [Compact Size](http://artscroll.com/Categories/HDT.html)

Exactly like the English version under the same title, but with commentary and elucidation in Modern Hebrew. Seventy-four volumes, like the English version.

- **Koren Talmud Bavli**

[Koren Talmud Bavli Set](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/talmud/the-koren-talmud-bavli/koren-talmud-bavli-complete-set.html)

Modern Hebrew translation with commentary by Rabbi Adin Steinsaltz.

Oz vehadar mesivta
Comprehensive commentry included full elucidation of tosfos

### French

- **The Edmond J. Safra Edition Talmud Bavli**

[The Edmond J. Safra Edition Talmud Bavli in French](http://artscroll.com/Categories/FRT.html)

Exactly like the Schottenstein English version, but with commentary and elucidation in French. Only 32 out of 73 volumes are available at this point, the others are in preparation.

Talmud Yerushalmi
Oz vehadar
Meorei Or

Comment: I recommend using some more [formatting](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to clearly separate entries. A bulletted list would probably be ideal. And it'd be good to set off sections with header formatting. I'd recommend adding a section for non-translated editions, even if you aren't ready to list any. I also suggest marking your answer "community wiki" (checkbox on bottom-right when you edit) to indicate that you welcome additions by other users.

Comment: Good list. Just one minor correction: The Soncino volumes do include the standard Vilna page as well. This is only the printed volumes though, the text online does not.

Comment: @Bachrach44 - Thanks I am currently trying to edit this answer so I'll make sure to include that.

Comment: you could add Jacob Neusners Bavli and Yerushalmi,however not really a great translation

Comment: @sam - This post is a Community Wiki; feel free to add it in where it belongs, according to the format I have set up.

Comment: @Meir - Bevakasha, achi! Glad we could help! Tell us which one you decide on!